# How do I use a GADM file to get coordinates?

Tags: maps, coordinates

I'm trying to make a Google Map or MyMap that will display a district in a red shape. I know I need the coordinates of the district from my country (France); I found [this link to download GADM data](https://gadm.org/download_country_v3.html).

But what can I do with this file? How can I get the coordinates from it?

I know the steps after that, with the coordinates, I need to use [this utility](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility?hl=fr).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to add a Google map to a website? If so, you can use Google Maps API to create a map and add a KML layer as shown here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml

I would not use a polyline utility at all. Download the data you need with the appropriate level (from 0 to 5) from the website you found in KMZ format, unpack it to extract KML and use it as a layer source with Google Maps API.

If your topic has to do with digital maps https://gis.stackexchange.com/ is where you can get answers faster.

See this simple example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Regions of France</title>
    <style>
        #map {
            height: 100%;
        }
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>

    function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 6,
            center: {lat: 47.147583, lng: 2.420839}
        });

        var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
            url: 'http://evnica.com/kml/France5.kml',
            map: map
        });
    }
</script>
<script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that you need to have a Google API key. The link to the KML file used in this example is temporary. If you want to use this file, please download it and host it on your server.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much Evnica. Im actually trying to create the map in google maps. Im checking this, and i will call you back if anything goes wrong. Thanks again !

Comment: I searched all day long, but cannot figure out how using Google maps API to pick out the coordinates into my KMZ file.

Comment: @Rogue, I have updated my answer with an example. I could not use the KMZ files from the website you have found, because they contained some errors. Instead, I have posted a temporary file that you can use if this is what you want. Hope it helps.